# Prove that if $f\in C^{r}$ then the map $g(u,x):=(df)_u(x)$ is of class $C^{r-1}$

Tags: analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be two finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-banach spaces and $U\subseteq X$ an open subset. Suppose that $f:U\to Y$ is of class $C^{r}$ with $r\geq 1$. Show that the map $g:U\times X\to Y$ given by $g(u,x):=(df)_u(x)$ is of class $C^{r-1}$.

---

Below is what I was able to prove when $f\in C^{\color{red}2}$.

Given a differentiable map $f:U\to Y$ we define $\color{red}{df}:U\to\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ by $df(u):=(df)_u$.

Define $h:U\times X\to \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ by $h(u,x):=d(df)(u)(x)$. I was able to prove that $h$ is continuous.

Let $\pi _1:U\times X\to U$ and $\pi _2:U\times X\to X$ be the canonical projections.

I proved that  $g$ is differentiable and $dg(u,x)=h(u,x)\circ \pi _1+df(u)\circ \pi _2$ for all $(u,x)\in U\times X$.

---

I tried use induction to finish the proof of that theorem but I failed.

If you know a reference that contains a proof of the above theorem please tell me!

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Choose a basis and describe $df$ in terms of the partial derivatives.